# Multiple return statements in if conditions in cellForRowAtIndexPath throw "Control may reach end of non-void function" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a cellForRowAtIndexPath method that goes like this

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    //add customCell1
    return customCell1;
}

else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

    //add customCell2
    return customCell2;
}
```

and so on, for each row.

I understand that the reason I'm getting this error is because my return statement is in a conditional statement. Why doesn't the compiler detect that every branch returns a value? Also, in this case, the conditional branching looks unavoidable to me, since I'm using different custom cells to populate each row of the table. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason compiler is complaining is because **your if condition is not exhaustive**. Here, you are checking for only 2 rows but number of rows will be deduced at run time and not at compile time. So, you must tell compiler all the cases you want it to handle.

So, the solution to your case (I believe you already know this), is to write an `else` in the end.

Comment: Just a `return nil;` at the end of the method works as well, although ideally it'd never actually be executed. Thank you!

Comment: I would advise to return a valid cell in else instead of `nil` to avoid any run time crashes. I understand that you know that you would not have more than 2 rows but its a safe practice to not make code susceptible to crash!

Comment: Please post a reason for down voting. I do not see a reason why I should get a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

What if the final ``` else if`` is false? You must at least have a final ```else`without an`if`.

Run the Analyzer and click in the statement toggle to show the path the analyzer took to find this warning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cover all the possibilities and it seems you are only covering for row 0 or 1.

You have to specify an else at the end that catch the other possibilities or simply a return at the end in case non of the "if" applies because the row is nor 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a value in Condition method,You must need to be specific that any of the condition will match so only "If" and "Else if" will not work,Also add "else" at the end and return respective cell.